# Filter using query string is not working in sveltekit. How to solve this?

Tags: typescript, filter, request, query-string, sveltekit

I used sveltekit,
and I implemented a filter which has selectbox with input and searchBtn.
Here is button event:

```js
async function handleSearchEvent(
    event: CustomEvent<{ role: string; category: string; input: string }>
) {
    const { role, category, input } = event.detail;

    goto(`?category=${category}&role=${role}&project_id=${_projectId}&nick_name=${input}&page=1`);
}
```

And here is my server side code which is +page.server.ts

```js
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit'; // import { fetchUserData, isFailure } from '$lib/api';

import { fetchSearchUser, fetchUsersData, isFailure, type Users } from '$lib/api';
import resolveSearchParam from '$lib/utils/resolveSearchParam.js';

type LoadResponse = {
    users: Users;
};

type LoadInput = {
    url: {
        href: string;
    };
    params: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
};

/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export async function load({ params, url }: LoadInput): Promise<LoadResponse> {
    console.log('clicked')
    const pageNum = resolveSearchParam(url.href, 'page', '1');
    const category = resolveSearchParam(url.href, 'category', '');
    const role = resolveSearchParam(url.href, 'role', '');
    const nickname = resolveSearchParam(url.href, 'nick_name', '');
    const projectId = params.project_id;

    const result = await fetchSearchUser(role, nickname, category, pageNum, projectId);

    if (isFailure(result)) {
        throw error(404, {
            message: 'Failed to get users',
            code: 'NOT_FOUND'
        });
    }


    console.log(result.data)


    return {
        users: result.data
    };
}
```

When I click the searchBtn I can checked the log and filter data, but not updated on the screen.
What is the problem and how to fix it?

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: check if you are not using reactivity wrong, some details are here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77085970/sveltekit-issue-getting-page-data-to-update-after-mounting

Comment: It was a problem caused by writing the resolveSearchParam function incorrectly. Thank you.