# Sveltekit issue getting Page data to Update after Mounting

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

So im pretty new at Svelte and Frontend Frameworks in general so I feel like this is a fairly basic issue. Im just new and havent run across this yet.

I have a category_[id] route with a page and a page.server.ts

on initial load everything is fine but if you hit one of the navigation buttons on the page to category_[othercategoryid] then nothing happens. I have console.log(ged) myself crazy trying to find where the logic is failing but the page it drabbing all the data just fine. Just isnt pushing it to the page dynamically. You can reload the page and everything pops right up but that isnt how it should be working

page.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
  export let data;
  const { products } = data.products;
  const { category } = data.category;
  const {categories} = data.categories;
  //console.log(products)
  //console.log(category)
  import ProductCard from '../../components/ProductCard.svelte';
 


</script>

<style> 
  .btn-custom {
  background-color: #FFCC33; /* Green */
  /* You can adjust other styles as needed */
  color: black; /* Text color */
  border-color:#FFCC33; /* Border color */  
  font-weight: 500;
  }
  .btn-custom:hover {
    background-color: #FCC200; /* New color for hover state */
  }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <!--Categories Page-->  
  <h1 class="text-center">{category.categoryname}</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="btn-group mb-3" role="group" aria-label="Categories">
      {#if categories}
      {#each categories as cat}
      <a href="/category_{cat.ID}" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-custom m-1">{cat.ID}</button></a>
      {/each}
      {/if}
    </div>
    <!-- Product Card  -->
    {#if products}
      {#each products as product}    
        {#if product.isfeatured == true && product.productstock > 0}
          <ProductCard product={product} />
        {/if}   
      {/each} 
    {/if} 

  </div>
</div>
```

+page.server.ts

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import Redis from 'ioredis';

// Parse the Redis URL with optional chaining and provide a default value
const redisUrl = new URL(process.env.REDIS ?? '');

const redisOptions = {
  host: redisUrl.hostname,
  port: parseInt(redisUrl.port), // Convert port to a number
  password: redisUrl.password,
  // Add other options as needed 
};

const redisClient = new Redis(redisOptions);

//redis cache data 

export const load = async ({ params }) => {
  const id = params.id;

  const cacheKey = `category:${id}`;
  //console.log('Load function started, category ID:', id);

  try {
    const cachedData = await redisClient.get(cacheKey);
    //console.log('Cached data:', cachedData);

    if (cachedData) {
      const { category, products } = JSON.parse(cachedData);
      //console.log('Using cached data:', category, products);
      
      return {
        category,
        products
      };
    } else {
      //console.log('No cached data found, fetching from API...');
      const category = await fetchCategory(id);
      const products = await fetchProducts(id);
      //console.log('Fetched data from API:', category, products);

      // Cache data in Redis with expiration (e.g., 1 hour/3600 seconds)
      await redisClient.setex(cacheKey, 3600, JSON.stringify({ category, products }));

      return {
        category,
        products
      };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    //console.error('Error accessing Redis cache:', error);
    // Handle the error gracefully
    return {
      category: null,
      products: []
    };
  }

};

const fetchCategory = async (id) => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://gunstorewebsite.com/apicategorybyid_${id}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};

const fetchProducts = async (id) => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://gunstorewebsite.com/apiproductsbycategory_${id}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};
```

im guessing the issue is in the page load data not updating when it needs to be updating but i dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that in Svelte components do not "rerender", rather their props get updated and pages are components. More specifically this means that the code in the `script` tag does not run again.

When you have this code

```js
export let data;
const { products } = data.products;
const { category } = data.category;
const {categories} = data.categories;
```

just `data` changes, but those lines do not run again, leaving you with the products, category and categories from the very first page.

You can easily fix this by marking these lines as reactive with `$:`

```js
export let data;
$: ({ products } = data.products);
$: ({ category } = data.category);
$: ({ categories } = data.categories);
```

that said, I find the destructuring a bit strange, looking at the code it means your result is of the format:

```
data.products.products
data.category.category
data.categories.categories
```

if you would clean that up such that these are direct properties of `data` you could do

```js
export let data;
$: ({ products, category, categories } = data);
```